# Is the best way to package jsvc with your java service as source code, then have people who use it compile before using?

Tags: java, jsvc

I've noticed that many open source projects use jsvc (the apache commons daemon) for wrapping a java program in a service. I've seen several ways of including it, as source or with binaries for common environments. Is source a preferred method?

Comment: Source code is always the method of choice for distributing free software.  Of course, you can *additionally* provide pre-compiled binaries for some popular platforms.

Comment: While not a technical reason to do so, some open source governance has very strict guidelines (legal reasons) on what is acceptable for [source] releases and what is not. If you're working on free software you should check what those rules are, regardless of the technical merit of the alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a well defined set of supported platforms (e.g. [like Apache BigTop)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BIGTOP-389) then you are better off sticking with source packaging.

Especially when JVSC is built with shared libraries, keeping your bundled binaries compatible across platforms is going to be a larger headache than it's worth. For a case study in this difficulty, you can read the problems [Hadoop ran into when it attempted to bundle JVSC](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2303) (they opted to skip even including source and went with requiring external installation)